# Images are stacking in other browsers besides Chrome with Easyslider 1.7

Tags: jquery, image, stacked

I've installed EasySlider1.7 and for some strange reason my images are stacking on top of each other. Any help would be nice. Thank you in advance!

here's the link http://www.gudskunc.com

Comment: BTW, Firefox and IE are the main browsers that are not complting with the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are hosted in Google Sites which you have password protected. You are logged in with Chrome so the files are accessible there, but on other browsers the loading fails.

Try to access https://sites.google.com/a/gudskunc.com/mediafiles/tech-web-css-and-more/jquery-css-html/easySlider1.7.js with another browser and you see what I mean.

Comment: Is there another way to host my files? Can I change https to http? Would that make a difference. And thank you for the quick response, Appreciate it!

Comment: I've changed the https to http and seem to be having the same problem?

Comment: I see, do you have  any solution on where to host my files?

Comment: Thank you Tatu you are the bomb! That fixed the problem! But now my images are not aligned, the # box is missing (replaced with 1,2,3,4,5) and it's not displayed on the white background.?!?! Any suggestions